# SSRS Expression to return previous month year value

Tags: reporting-services, power-bi-report-server

I'm trying to come up with an SSRS expression to return a previous value from the year prior. As you can see in the screenshot, I'm trying to return the value of 22 in the "Prior Year Actual" column. This value aligns with April 2020. The last month I have in the dataset currently is April 2021. Essentially I want to return the value from the year prior based on the last column of April 2021.

Can anyone help with this? Greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: It's not very clear what you need.. do you want to return data one year prior to the last column (April 2021)? so if the last column was May 2021, you want May 2020 Value?

Comment: Harry, that's 100% correct.  Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: probably better done in SQL rather than in the report to be honest

Comment: That's what I thought as well.  This table created in our EDW (by someone else) is absolute crap.  :) No ideas how to do this with an expression though?  I wish with Last and Previous you could specify a column to return a value.

Comment: Are there any month/year fields in the dataset on which the column group is based on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your month fields are dates in a column group, you could get the MAX date and add it to the dataset.

```
DECLARE @MAX_DATE DATE = (SELECT MAX(DATE_FIELD) FROM TABLE)

SELECT *, @MAX_DATE AS MAX_DATE 
FROM TABLE
```

Then your expression could use the new field to make it work like you want.

```
=MAX(IIF(Fields!Date.Value = DATEADD("y", -1, Fields!MAX_DATE.Value), Fields!COLUMN.Value, NOTHING))
```

Comment: Thank you Hannover.  When trying this formula I am receiving an error.  I made sure to change month and year to a date.  This is the error: "The Value expression for the text box 'Textbox457' has a nested aggregate that specifies a dataset scope.  Inner aggregates cannot specify a dataset scope."  Any idea what might be up?  Thanks!

Comment: I actually figured out this error using this formula: =MAX(IIF(Fields!Month_Name.Value= DATEADD("y", -1, MAX(Fields!Month_Name.Value)), Fields!Month_Name.Value, NOTHING)).  However, it doesn't return anything.

Comment: @BuffaloBill - your expression is not working because the IIF is working on a single record so the max is the same. That's why I tried the scope that also didn't work. Is your month field a date or text? I've updated my answer to add a max date field to the dataset - not sure how else to do it.

Comment: your suggestion did work for me and I marked your answer as correct.  It just needed a little tweaking.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This worked! Thank you very much Hannover for your expression suggestion!!

=MAX(IIF(Fields!DateTest.Value= DATEADD("yyyy", -1, MAX(Fields!DateTest.Value)), Fields!Operating_Days.Value, NOTHING))